# Inicializar array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

Tengo una duda y no se como resolverla.

Tengo este array creado:

```
var data: [(x: Double, y: Double)]
```

Al intentar usarlo me dice que no está inicializado.

Me podéis decir como inicializarlo, no consigo hacerlo.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: var data  = [(x: Double, y: Double)]()

Comment: Perfecto, gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas fácil es inicializarlo vacio en la misma declaración

```
var data: [(x: Double, y: Double)] = []
```

o si le quieres darle valores, por ejemplo

```
var data: [(x: Double, y: Double)] = [(2.4, 3.5), (0.4, 5.5)]
```